# Is there a simple way to add a variable string to an element attribute without "setAttribute"?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to take data from another part of the element and add it to another (force lazy-loading images to load) and everything I find points me towards setAttribute however this breaks the data as it automatically adds a equals and quotations to the added data which breaks it.

So:

```
images[i].setAttribute('data-anim-src',' srcset= "'+images[i].getAttribute('data-srcset')+'"');
```

Gets me `data-anim-src=" srcset="...""` instead of what I want which is `data-anim-src srcset="..."`

Is there any way to remove the ="" that's automatically added with setAttribute? or is there an equally simple alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setAttribute` works like this:

```js
setAttribute(attribute, value);
```

not like this:

```js
setAttribute(attribute1, attribute2, attribute3);
```

So to solve it, just set them separately:

```
images[i].setAttribute('data-anim-src', 'true');
images[i].setAttribute('srcset', images[i].getAttribute('data-srcset'));
```